Android: which Listener for EditText SearchView?
So Android code includes AddTextChangedListener that implements TextWatcher() and its methods.  Android also includes OnQueryTextListener() and its methods.  And there are many uses cases listed here on stackoverflow for each.
I have set up a SearchView on EditTexts.  The EditTexts populate CardViews in a Recyclerview list of items.  In this case, which listener is preferred for text input and search?
**private TextWatcher search = new TextWatcher()** {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};

versus:

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ...
    **searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);**        
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    //
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    //
}


TextWatcher would need to explicitly capture the enter/submit button

@OneCricketeer ty, for the edits...I will investigate on the capture.

The android docs suggest using QueryTextListener

@OneCricketeer Ok, can you point me toward the docs so I can review?

Since SearchView doesn't extend EditText, then TextWatcher cannot be added to a SearchView.

@OneCricketeer The posts I've seen do this for TextWatcher() search:
"editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {}".

EditText does not support setOnQueryTextListener and SearchView doesn't have addTextChangedListener. I'm not understanding what you mean by "SearchView on EditText" since SearchView is an individual widget... Which listener you use doesn't really matter since the actual search functionality isn't built-into either one. As mentioned, the SearchView would only give you the whole search string, rather than positional values
